# JSONP not working for me throwing an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parsing, jsonp

Im trying to retrieve a feed or at least get a success, but for some reason it's not working for me. Please help

```js
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.canadiantire.ca/ws/ajax_call.jsp?proc_class=com.ctc.ajax.CTCRequestAjaxHandler&action=getTabProductInfo&locale=en&pTab=1&pSku=0853086,0853694,0853693,0853076,0853082,0853662&callback=?',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsonp',

    success: function(data) {
      alert('success');

    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Sorry, I can't get the feed");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply open that URL in browser and see it is not returning `jsonp`.
SOme API's that do serve jsonp require a specific callback value or other parameters to be sent. Not all API's do serve jsonp though. See API docs.

If you try to request as json, you get a cross domain error since server is not CORS enabled.

Not all API's are accessible via ajax and the fallback is to use a proxy

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. If I want to retrieve the data/value and put in my own personal page, how would you suggest to do this?

Comment: @icovermaface proxify it server side

Comment: which means create a server side script that gets the json, and make the ajax point at your server script

Comment: @charlietfl - How would I do that? I pretty new to this, will you be able to create a jsfiddle example for me ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to add this inside ajax call. Reference http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

```
 data: { format: "json" },
```

Comment: that doesn't have any universal recognition. It's all API dependent

Comment: I am still getting 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token :' issue,